# Raspberry Pi with iRobot Create 2

Tags: serial

I am a noob coder. I am trying to control the iRobot Create 2 from my Raspberry Pi. As far as I have found out, to talk to the robot I need to send strings representing hex values of predefined structure.

E.g. to go forward at a velocity of 200mm/s I need to send '\x91\x00\xc8\x00\xc8' through the serial Tx pin.

I want to input velocity from keyboard (say 100 in decimal, so 0x64 in hex). But I cannot figure out how to do so, because of the backslash "\" in the string, simple operations, like `.replace` are not working.

Let me sum up what I need:

> v = velocity   ## the user will input velocity in decimal, say 100
>
> Vh = hex(v)    ## decimal to hex conversion, gives me some value like 0x64

command = '\x91\x00\x00\x00\x00' will be replaced by '\x91\x00\x64\x00\x64'

I need to write the command through serial Tx

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely there are meant to be backslashes in the string.

I believe the intention is to show that you will be sending binary data rather than text.

"x91\x00\xc8\x00\xc8" is saying that you must send 5 bytes.  The bytes being 0x91 0x00 0xc8 0x00 and 0xc8.

From the command line you could send those bytes to the serial link with the command

echo -n -e "x91\x00\xc8\x00\xc8" >/dev/ttyAMA0

where the -n option says no new line and the -e option says interpret escape sequence in strings.

In C terms you would have a char array dimensioned for the maximum command string.

Then, say,

```
char cmd[128];

cmd[0] = 0x91;
cmd[1] = 0;
cmd[2] = 0xc8;
cmd[3] = 0;
cmd[4] = 0xc8;

write(fd, cmd, 5);
```

where fd is the file descriptor for the serial link.